# Como realizar uma predição usando modelo de Regressão Linear Multivariada no R?

Tags: r

Estou estudando soluções para realizar uma predição de um produto que depende de outras variáveis.

Nesse meu estudo estou usando como minha base de dados `Seatbelts`, uma Série Temporal que já é nativa do R. Que se trata de uma série histórica de acidentes de carros com morte de 1969 a 1983.

Nessa base possui oito variáveis, sendo que meu objetivo é usar a variável `DriversKilled`(Motoristas Mortos) para criar um modelo preditivo que preveja a quantidade de Motoristas Mortos nos próximos 5 anos.

```
colnames(Seatbelts)

[1] "DriversKilled" "drivers"       "front"         "rear"          "kms"          
[6] "PetrolPrice"   "VanKilled"     "law"
```

Usando o modelo de Regressão Linear `tslm` e incluindo as variáveis `trend`(tendência) e `season`(sazonalidade), consegui fazer a previsão usando a função `Forecast` com sucesso.

```
mortos = window(Seatbelts[,c("DriversKilled")], start = c(1975,1), end= c(1984,12))

treino = window(mortos, start=c(1975,1), end=c(1979,12))

teste = window(mortos, start=c(1980,1), end=c(1984,12))

modelo_1 = tslm(treino ~ trend + season, data = treino)

Prev1 = forecast(modelo_1, h = 60)

plot(mortos)
lines(Prev1$mean, col="red")
```

[image: Previsão Regressão Linear em Vermelho]

Como visto na imagem acima, a cor vermelha indica a previsão usando a Regressão Linear, porém quero melhorá-la, considerando outras variáveis como por exemplo a variável `drivers`(motoristas), com toda certeza esta variável influencia no número de mortos e se ela for incluída em meu modelo posso melhorar a acurácia da minha previsão.

É aí que começa meu problema, venho tentando acrescentar outras variáveis no meu modelo de Regressão Linear, mas não consigo fazer que a função `Forecast` reconheça essas novas variáveis. Como posso fazer isso? É possível?

Como posso realizar uma predição usando um modelo de Regressão Linear Múltipla ou Multivariada no R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que passar os novos dados como uma `data frame` como `newdata` para a função `forecast`.
Sendo que o nome das colunas do `data frame` tem que bater com o nome das variáveis do modelo.

```
library(forecast)

mortos = window(Seatbelts[,c("DriversKilled")], start = c(1975,1), end= c(1984,12))
motoristas = window(Seatbelts[,c("drivers")], start = c(1975,1), end= c(1984,12))

treino_mot <- window(motoristas, start=c(1975,1), end=c(1979,12))
teste_mot <-data.frame(
  treino_mot = window(motoristas, start=c(1980,1), end=c(1984,12))
) #cria um data frame com uma coluna de nome treino_mot, mesmo nome usado no modelo

treino = window(mortos, start=c(1975,1), end=c(1979,12))
teste = window(mortos, start=c(1980,1), end=c(1984,12))

modelo_1 = tslm(treino ~ trend + season + treino_mot) #modelo com motoristas
modelo_2 = tslm(treino ~ trend + season) #modelo sem motoristas

Prev1 = forecast(modelo_1, h = 60)
Prev2 <- forecast(modelo_1, newdata =  teste_mot, h = 60)

#compara os três
plot(mortos)
lines(Prev1$mean, col="red") #com motoristas e sem novos dados
lines(Prev2$mean, col = "blue") #com motoristas e novos dados para os motoristas
```

Ou pra ficar mais organizado, trabalhar mais com `data frames`:

```
library(forecast)

treino = window(Seatbelts, start=c(1975,1), end=c(1979,12))
teste = as.data.frame(window(Seatbelts, start=c(1980,1), end=c(1984,12)))

modelo_1 = tslm(DriversKilled ~ trend + season, data = treino) #modelo sem motoristas
modelo_2 = tslm(DriversKilled ~ trend + season + drivers, data = treino) #modelo com motoristas

Prev1 = forecast(modelo_1, h = 60)
Prev2 = forecast(modelo_2, newdata = teste, h = 60)

#compara os dois
plot(Seatbelts[,"DriversKilled"])
lines(Prev1$mean, col="red")
lines(Prev2$mean, col = "blue")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta vou testar.